# Go is not writing complete data to text file

Tags: go

I am trying to explore Go concurrency. Here `Grabber()` prints and writes the result of the execution. The program prints the expected result, but does not write it to `urls.txt`. Can anyone explain to me what i am missing here?

> main.go

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mt sync.Mutex

// Final Literation
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("ip.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        go Grabber(scanner.Text())
        wg.Add(1)

    }
    wg.Wait()

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// stringInArray do If string in list return true false otherwise.
func stringInArray(a string, list []string) bool {
    for _, b := range list {
        if b == a {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// Grabber Do Search the bing and collect array of sitelist
func Grabber(ip string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    var output []string
    outfile, err := os.Create("urls.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer outfile.Close()
    if ip == "" {

    }
    page := 1
    for page < 251 {
        client := &http.Client{}
        req, err := http.NewRequest(
            http.MethodGet,
            fmt.Sprintf(
                "http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip:%s+&count=50&first=1",
                ip,
            ),
            nil,
        )
        if err != nil {

        }
        req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0")
        res, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Invalid Request")
        }
        defer res.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Couldn't Read")
        }
        re := regexp.MustCompile(`<h2><a href="(.*?)"`)
        links := re.FindAllString(string(body), -1)
        if links != nil {
            for l := range links {
                o := strings.Split(links[l], `"`)
                d := strings.Split(o[1], "/")
                s := d[0] + "//" + d[2]
                if !stringInArray(s, output) {
                    output = append(output, s)
                }
            }
        }
        page = page + 50
    }
    for _, links := range output {
        fmt.Println(links)
        fmt.Fprintln(outfile, links)
    }
}
```

> Ip.txt as input

```
103.253.145.129
103.253.146.125
103.253.146.239
103.253.147.72
146.185.176.79
146.185.176.45
146.185.179.250
146.185.180.35
146.185.180.185
146.185.180.113
146.185.181.51
146.185.183.107
146.185.183.202
146.185.183.248
146.185.183.219
146.185.184.69
146.185.185.169
```

git repo [URLGrabber](https://github.com/ArifulProtik/URLGrabber)

Comment: Is it printing them to console?

Comment: All goroutines are creating/truncating the same file. Instead of creating the file multiple times, create it once, start another goroutine writing to the file as it reads from a channel, and pass that channel to all the workers, so goroutines won't erase each other's work.

Comment: @Adrian Yes It is

Comment: @BurakSerdar Can you Explain it? I am New to the golang. Or Some resouces regarding your comment will do the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `create` in each goroutine, which will truncate the file. Instead, create the file outside, and serialize the writes to it using another goroutine:

```
    outfile, err := os.Create("urls.txt")
    results:=make(chan []string)
    go func() {
       for output:=range results { 
          for _, links := range output {
            fmt.Fprintln(outfile, links)
          }      
       }
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        go Grabber(scanner.Text(), results)
        wg.Add(1)

    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)
```

When you get the results in Grabber, instead of writing it to the file, write it to the channel:

```
    results<-output
    for _, links := range output {
        fmt.Println(links)
    }
```

Comment: As it stands main may exit before the writing goroutine is done. The range loop should be in the main goroutine, and the scanner loop, Wait and close should be "in the background".

Comment: @Peter, main cannot exit before writing is done. Writing goroutine stops after wg.wait() at which point there is nothing else to write.